# Does Yesod have a development-time analogue to Play's SBT ~run command

Tags: yesod

One of the truly great things about Play and SBT is the 'hot compile' option. Makes the development workflow astoundingly productive. Does Yesod currently (or future?) have this similar ability? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm actually not at all familiar with Play and SBT. A description of what that feature is would allow people familiar with Yesod and not Play to answer this question.

Comment: I've worked with Play2 for Java, so this is from my perspective: you can run an application with the `play ~run` command, the effect of which is automatic re-deployment of an app – both Java controllers and templates would be compiled and swapped at runtime and changes are seen immediately. So yes, as the answer below states, `yesod devel` is probably the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `yesod devel` command which automatically rebuilds and runs the project.